# CSS Grid Columns Not Working As Intended For Title Line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

https://codepen.io/Surgemus/pen/MWpwVeb

I'm trying to get a Title Header where the text is followed by a line to fill the whitespace to the right.
I tried using `grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;` and it works, up until the first column is the size of the grid itself. What should happen is instead of the text being cut off, it would word-wrap itself, while hiding the HR line. I only did this in `display:grid` becuase it worked. If there is a way to evenly space *without* using grid, I'm open to the idea.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `display: flex` and set a `max-width: 100%` and `flex-shrink: 0` on the span.

```css
main {
  width: min(1000px, 94vw);
  margin: 8vh auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

main>div {
  padding: 2%;
  background: #333;
}

main>div:nth-child(even) {
  background: #555;
}

.title {
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  display: flex;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.title span {
  margin: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
}

hr {
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 150%;
  list-style: square;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>
    <div class="title"><span>Short Title</span>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <p>When the title is shorter like this, there is no issue. The line is supposed to adjust with the size of the main element.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="title"><span>Super Long  Issue-Causing Title</span>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <p>Now, the title is so long, that when the main element becomes smaller, the issue becoems apparent. I want the HR line to just disappear and have the title text wrap. Not sure if this is a grid issue or what.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="title"><span>Medium Sized Title</span>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <p>Random text goes here. Random text goes here. Random text goes here. Random text goes here. Random text goes here. Random text goes here. Random text goes here. </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="title"><span>Another Title</span>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <p>Random text goes here. Random text goes here. Random text goes here. Random text goes here. Random text goes here. Random text goes here. Random text goes here. </p>
  </div>

</main>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/sforsberg/pen/JjWdLJv